# Duplicate entries in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm getting duplicate entries for several contents in my latex pdf.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\include{Abstract/abstract}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}
\include{Abbreviations/loa}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Chapter1/ch1}
\include{Chapter2/ch2}

\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage
\include{Appendix/appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References/myref}
\rhead{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ProjectDetail}
\include{ProjectDetail/PD}
```

In list of table I'm getting duplicate entries with same page number of list of figures, list of tables and references. Rest of the content is fine.
Any idea how to remove those?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. Knowing the document class you're using is essential, please edit your question to add the information.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to say what the  exact cause of the double entries is with the supplied code. Could you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Removing the `\addcontentsline`s as hbaderts suggests will likely fix the issue, but the default is usually not to add LoF/LoT/Bibl to the ToC. Have you by any chance `\usepackage{tocbibind}` in the preamble?

Answer (score 3):

Without a minimal working example, which includes the documentclass and your packages, all we can do is guessing.

With some documentclasses and/or packages, the list of tables, list of figures and bibliography are already added to the table of contents. 
For example if you are using KOMA-script classes with the `listof=totoc` option, the LOF and LOT are added to the table of contents.
Similarly, the `bibliography=totoc` option puts the bibliography (references) into the TOC. From the described problem, I assume that you have such options activated or you load packages which do the same.

Yet you separately add the LOF, LOT and bibliography to the TOC using `\addcontentsline{toc}{...}{...}`. As (probably) you already do this via the documentclass or packages, this causes the duplicate entries.

So, just remove the `\addcontentsline{toc}{...}{...}` to remove the duplicates, or have a closer look at the documentclass options and packages.

Comment: By default? This depends on the documentclass or on the used package(s)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer oh you are right of course, thanks for the hint. As I always use KOMA-script with the corresponding options, it was clear to me that the duplicates are caused by something like that. I tried to generalize my answer to reflect this, though without a MWE this is just guesswork.